# Error occurs when react Modal is surrounded by Portal

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react.
I have created a Portal component.
When I enclose a modal in Portal, I get the following error in VsCode.
If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

Error Description

```
Type '{ children: Element[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNode'.
  Type '{ children: Element[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

```
// portal.tsx
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

export const Portal = (children: React.ReactNode) => {
  const el = document.getElementById('portal');
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, el);
};
```

```
  <Portal>
      <Overlay/>
      <Modal
        padding={padding}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        radius={radius}
        overflowY={overflowY}
      >
        {children}
      </Modal>
    </Portal>
```

Answer (score 0):

### **`createPortal` receive a single React Node, so you will need to wrap it inside another `<></>` (React.Fragment):**

**This is `createPortal` type:**

```
export function createPortal(
  children: ReactNode,
  container: Element,
  key?: null | string
): ReactPortal;
```

**So you would need to change your code to:**

```
<Portal>
  <>
    <Overlay />
    <Modal
      padding={padding}
      width={width}
      height={height}
      radius={radius}
      overflowY={overflowY}
    >
      {children}
    </Modal>
  </>
</Portal>;
```

**And in your `portal.tsx`**

```
export const Portal: React.FunctionComponent<React.ReactNode> = ({
  children
}) => {
  const el = document.getElementById("portal");
  if (el) return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, el);
  return null;
};
```

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit agitated-microservice-8zsew]

Comment: I added the export function createPortal to Portal.tsx, but an error occurred.
Error contents
Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.ts(23)
Cannot find name 'ReactPortal'.ts(2304)

Comment: No no, `createPortal` is only a type I put there for clarify, you don't need to copy it to your code.

Comment: Just wrap your children with <></> inside your `<Portal>`

Comment: I enclosed it in <></>, but the error didn't go away.

Comment: Can I have access to your solution?

Comment: What do you mean by access to solutions?

Comment: I mean your github repo or codesanbox example? There must be something else with your code. wrapping your children around React.Fragment should solve the issue already.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-cloud-86xf2?file=/src/components/Drawer.tsx

Comment: I updated my answer, I realized that there is a bit more issue with your code. Please correct your type in `portal.tsx` and check for null before using createPortal. Your codesanbox doesn't contain any element with `id="portal"`

Comment: I attach a fixed version of your codesanbox in the answer. Tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: Thank you. The error disappeared, but the modal is not displayed anymore, but the modal is displayed when I remove the portal.